# Exclamation point (!) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

The following code is designer generated:

```
Me.lblXRay.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
```

What does `8.0!` mean?

Comment: in addition to [type character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters), it is also [member access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/special-characters-in-code#member-access-operators)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This dates back to very early versions of Microsoft Basic.  These type characters let you both set the type of an identifier and a literal:

```
    Dim singleVar! = 1.2!
    Dim doubleVar# = 1.2#
    Dim decimalVar@ = 1.2@
    Dim integerVar% = 12%
    Dim longVar& = 12&
    Dim stringVar$ = "12"

    Function ReturnsString$(ByVal takesLong&)
```

Answer (score 7):

It means type *Single*. See *[Single Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type)* (under section *Programming Tips*).

Answer (score 5):

From the [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) library:

> **Type Characters**. Appending the literal type character F to a literal forces it to the Single data type. Appending the identifier type character ! to any identifier forces it to Single.

Comment: `8.0` is a literal though, not an identifier

Answer (score 2):

****Here is a Cheat Sheet for DataTypes ****

Variable End with:

```
$ : String
% : Integer (Int16)
& : Long (Int32)
! : Single
# : Double
@ : Decimal
```

Start with:

```
&H : Hex
&O : Octal
```

Comparison between VB and VB.Net ([reference](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/datatypes.html))

Visual Studio .Net added Literal Types ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters))

Value End with: (For more complete list, refer the the reference)

```
S : Short (Int16)
I : Integer (Int32)
L : Long (Int64)
F : Single
R : Double
D : Decimal
```