# Does the 'bang' operator (!) in VB6 mean anything if it is merely on the end of a variable/number? If so, what does it mean?

Tags: vb6, operators

I am working on some VB6 code at work and frequently come across variables, and sometimes numerical values ending with '!'. For example (note the '!' at the end of `myVar!` and the second `2!`:

```
dist! = Sqr(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2!)
```

This is a line from the code I am working on. Does the '!' hold any meaning here? I would assume it does, because why use it otherwise, but can't find any documentation on this particular use.

Comment: I believe that it indicates the data type is floating-point (like $ indicates string). But I'm drawing on vague memories of vintage-1980s MBasic, which may not apply at all.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037058/vb-net-exclamation-point) or the documentation! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: [What do ! and # mean when attached to numbers in VB6? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888921/what-do-and-mean-when-attached-to-numbers-in-vb6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's no an operator, it's a type indicator.  An Exclamation/Bang at the end of the name indicates a variable that can hold single precision floating point value.  Here's a list of VB type indicators (may not be complete):

```
$ - string 
% - integer 
& - long integer 
! - single precision floating point
# - double precision floating point 
@ - currency
```